# TV remote no longer working

Tags: audio, kodi, openelec

I'm running openelec+xbmc connected to my TV via HDMI cable, and my TV remote has stopped being able to control XBMC.

I'm not sure if it is the settings in xbmc/openelec that are incorrect, if there is something funny with the TV, or if it is the cable or the rpi itself.

I've power-cycled the TV and the rpi separately and together, and I can see that the remote is working OK because it controls the TV as usual. My TV is a panasonic TH-P42S10Z.

I have a possibly related issue of sound no longer working, when it previously did.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: I found that having a powered on Android TV connected regularised the Pi in such a way that ECE always works. YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three HDMI ports on this TV. The CEC is passed through port #1 only. Connecting the RPi to port #1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I once found that connecting a second rpi to my tv stopped the remote from working on the first. Even after removing the rpi (but leaving the cable connected to the tv) this remained the same. I got the impression that there may be a sensing mechanism that was at work here. I'm not sure this will help you, but have you added a new hdmi device to your tv lately?

Comment: The rpi is the newest thing in the mix for me.

Comment: I can confirm Jos' experience. I'm using a Philips TV. I 'removed' the pi from the devicelist in the televisions *settings*, and added it again, that worked. Later I had the idea that in these settings there was a possibility to set the CEC option (EasyLink for Philips, for Panasonic its **VIERA Link** or **HDAVI Control** or **EZ-Sync**)

Comment: The forum at raspberrypi.org reports of various forms of erratic behaviour for ECE with the Pi. Some suggest that a factory reset of the TV set helps fixing the issue. Other errors are traced back to the ESD protective circuit of the Pi (but those are only of relevance if the Pi is powered down).